# Connect 3 different echart graphs with null series-line data

Tags: javascript, echarts

I am able to successfully connect 3 different graphs with the connect API.

```
let echart_instance_1 = type1.current.getEchartsInstance();
let echart_instance_2 = type2.current.getEchartsInstance();
let echart_instance_3 = type3.current.getEchartsInstance();

echarts.connect([echart_instance_1, echart_instance_2, echart_instance_3]);
```

All 3 graphs are connected so whenever I hover over echart_instance_1, the other 2 will follow the tooltip, but the problem comes when `null` data is in the series.data and multiple series.data.

```
series: [
{
   type: "line"
   connectNulls: true,
   data: [1, 2, 3, 4, null, null, null, null]
},
{
   type: "line"
   connectNulls: true,
   data: [null, null, null, null, 5, 6, 7, null]
},
{
   type: "line"
   connectNulls: true,
   data: [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 8]
}
]
```

It breaks apart the connection when you hover over the graph.
Is there any way to maintain the connection for the other series.data?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the problem live only on your local, it can't reproduce with minimal config. You need to publish full config here or carefully look for problems on the local machine. With provided data it works like a charm, see below.

```js
var myChart1 = echarts.init(document.getElementById('main1'));
var myChart2 = echarts.init(document.getElementById('main2'));
var myChart3 = echarts.init(document.getElementById('main3'));

// Unsert your code below
var option = {
  tooltip: {},
  xAxis: {
    data: ["Category1", "Category2", "Category3", "Category4", "Category5", "Category6", "Category7", "Category8"]
  },
  yAxis: {},
  series: [{
      type: "line",
      connectNulls: true,
      data: [1, 2, 3, 4, null, null, null, null]
    },
    {
      type: "line",
      connectNulls: true,
      data: [null, null, null, null, 5, 6, 7, null]
    },
    {
      type: "line",
      connectNulls: true,
      data: [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 8]
    }
  ]
};

// Unsert your code above
myChart1.setOption(option);
myChart2.setOption(option);
myChart3.setOption(option);

echarts.connect([myChart1, myChart2, myChart3]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/echarts@4.9.0/dist/echarts.min.js"></script>
<div id="main1" style="width: 600px;height:200px;"></div>
<div id="main2" style="width: 600px;height:200px;"></div>
<div id="main3" style="width: 600px;height:200px;"></div>
```